# JSlider major tick spacing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jslider

My `JSlider` first value is `0` and the last value is `8850`. I want to set the major tick spacing so that the last value (`8850`) to be printed. For example if I set the major tick spacing to `550` the last value printed will be `8800`.

Comment: "*For example if I set the major tick spacing to 550 the last value printed will be 8850.*". So, you solved it. So, what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post

Comment: the last value printed is 8800

Comment: Yes you can call `slider.setMajorTickSpacing(550);`, but don't forget to call `slider.setPaintTicks(true);` and `slider.setPaintLabels(true);`

Comment: the labels are painted... like I said i want the 8850 value to be painted even if 8800 + the major tick spacing 550 in this example is over 8850

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`JSlider#setLabelTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setLabelTable%28java.util.Dictionary%29) method to control which labels are painted. The [`JSlider#createStandardLabels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#createStandardLabels%28int%29) avoids that you have to manually create all labels. It is sufficient to use that method to generate them for you, and just add your label for the max value to it.

The [Swing slider tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html#labels) even has sample code how to use custom labels